# Customize footer of a presentation

Tags: beamer, header-footer, presentations

I've got few questions:
 - First, I want to remove the school name from the footer and instead need the abbreviation (like for Massachusetts Institute of Technology, need MIT) within parenthesis next to my name.
 - Next, as the second item of the footer, the slide heading, for eg. Outline, Introduction etc.
 - Lastly, as the third item, conference name and the institutions logo.

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}       % or try default, Darmstadt, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{serif}    % or try default, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[%
  physical paper width=8in, physical paper height=6in]

\title[Molecules in \LaTeX{}]{A short presentation on molecules in \LaTeX{}}
\author{J. Hammersley}
\institute{www.overleaf.com}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I want to remove the school name from the footer and instead need the abbreviation (like for Massachusetts Institute of Technology, need MIT) within parenthesis next to my name

If you specify the *institution* as

`\institute[MIT]{Massachusetts Institute of Technology}`

then you will get what you want.

2. As the second item of the footer, the slide heading, for eg. Outline, Introduction etc. - Lastly, as the third item, conference name and the institutions logo.

To achieve this you need to redefine the footline template that beamer is using. If you look inside `beamerthemeMadrid.sty` you see that the Madrid theme uses `\useoutertheme{infolines}`. Looking at `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty` you can have the same look and feel as the Madrid theme but with what you want in the different slots by using:

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{% override the footline from Madrid
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\ifnum\thepage=1\insertshorttitle\else\insertframetitle\fi
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \insertconferencename \quad \raisebox{-0.5mm}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{example-image}}\hspace*{2mm}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

All that I have done compared with the `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty` is to add the line

```
\ifnum\thepage=1\insertshorttitle\else\insertframetitle\fi
```

so that the title page (ie. when `\thepage` is equal to 1) uses the short title and the other pages use the frame title. Of course, if you don't give a frame title, using `\frametitle{...}`, this will cause problems.

Secondly, the lines

```
\insertconferencename \quad 
\raisebox{-0.5mm}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{example-image}}
```

add the conference name, which you will need to specify, antogether with a "fake" logo, which I have forced into the right place using `\raisebox`. To specify the conference, use `\conference{<Conference name>}` and replace the `example-image` with an image for your logo.

With this in place the [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) below produces:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}% for a fake logo example-image

% define a \conference command for setting the conference name
\newcommand\conference[1]{\def\insertconferencename{#1}}
\providecommand\insertconferencename{*conference?*}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}       % or try default, Darmstadt, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{serif}    % or try default, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{% override the footline from Madrid
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\ifnum\thepage=1\insertshorttitle\else\insertframetitle\fi
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \insertconferencename \quad \raisebox{-0.5mm}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{example-image}}\hspace*{2mm}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[%
  physical paper width=8in, physical paper height=6in]

\title[Molecules in \LaTeX{}]{A short presentation on molecules in \LaTeX{}}
\author{J. Hammersley}
\institute[MIT]{Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{First frame}
  A frame
\end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time in this clear explanation.